# MongoDB Compass - stuck on connecting to Atlas

Tags: mongodb

Every time I try to connect to MongoDB Atlas cluster, Compass gets stuck in some never-stop-loading bug.
There is no error of any kind, not even in dev-tools.
If I try to connect to localhost, everything works fine.
Atlas connection string is never recognized automatically, if that means something.
I need to paste it manually, and after I click connect, white overlay is shown and that's it.
I disabled firewall, reinstalled mongoDb from my computer, tried to restart service couple of times ...nothing helps.

White overlay after clicking on connect:

[image]

ps. I have a cluster created, with mongoDB user and white-listed my IP.
pps. compass version is 1.20.5, windows 10

Comment: Click on the menu "View > Toggle DevTools" and see whether there's any specific error messages that you're able to post here.

Comment: no errors in dev tools

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sorry I just figured it out.

- You need to go to "Connect" in Atlas, go to "Connect Your Application" (NOT "Connect with MongoDB Compass")
- Change Node.js version to "2.2.12 or later"
- Copy connection string as normal, replace password and paste in Compass

Edit: I've come up with even more details - the underlying problem could be your DNS. Try to replace it with the Google DNS for example (8.8.8.8) to see if it fixes the issue and continue using the up-to-date connection string.

Comment: ok, that helped. I fallowed your instructions and Compass connected without problems immediately. Thank you

Comment: I think the crucial thing was to use  Node.js version "2.2.12 or later". Can't remember now, but I did some combinations, and only this passed.

Comment: It's definitely the DNS. I tried with my default DNS and could only use the 2.2.12 Node string (without srv), when I switch to 8.8.8.8 both strings work.

Comment: The Node.js version seems to be the one for me. Only changed the node.js version and worked right away

Answer (score 2):

It could be a permissions thing, try running as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

- Uninstalling/Installing the latest MongoDB Compass version
- Double checking workstation authorizes MongoDB port outgoing requests (27017 by default, but it shouldn't be needed as you disabled your firewall)
- Double checking your IP address is indeed in the IP whitelist (that would be my first guess)
- Double checking your user has read permission in the cluster
- Double checking the connection string, in MongoDB Atlas click on "Connect", indicate Atlas and copy/paste

For the IP whitelist, just to be sure you can check it by going to MongoDB Atlas https://account.mongodb.com/, click in the left column on Security > Network

[image: MongoDB Atlas left column]

Then double check your IP is here (it will be indicated), otherwise click on "Add IP address".

[image]

Comment: i did all those previously many times, nothing helps, compass just freezes. (I allowed all IPs, downloaded different versions of compass, community edition or with mongoDB installation, firewall, string checking...)

Answer (score 0):

I am using the 4.4.6 version
Following these steps may help you,

> Network access : **0.0.0.0/0 (or your personal IP)**

> Database access : **readWriteAnyDatabase**

> Choose **connect to your application**

you will get a string like :

> mongodb+srv://admin:@sickcluster.a87o5.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority

change the admin, Password with brackets<>, and myFirstDatabase values {database name is optional}

> now paste this URL in your MongoDb compass and application