# Cannot connect to atlas cluster db from mongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-compass

So I was following this MongoDB tutorial and it tells me to make a hosted database with atlas MongoDB and then connect it with compass, but after I filled the connection fields it always shows this error

```
Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
```

My MongoDB Server is running in the background and I have tried changing the cluster password and this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/60416687/11652306 but the problem still persist.

I've tried connecting via mongo shell and it gives me this log

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00.kupeh.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.kupeh.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.kupeh.mongodb.net:27017/test?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=atlas-ty53k9-shard-0&ssl=true
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T14:15:13.284Z"},"s":"W",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23019,   "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"DNS resolution while connecting to peer was slow","attr":{"peer":"cluster0-shard-00-00.kupeh.mongodb.net:27017","durationMillis":1302}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T14:15:13.792Z"},"s":"W",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23019,   "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"DNS resolution while connecting to peer was slow","attr":{"peer":"cluster0-shard-00-02.kupeh.mongodb.net:27017","durationMillis":1810}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T14:15:26.981Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4333208, "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"RSM host selection timeout","attr":{"replicaSet":"atlas-ty53k9-shard-0","error":"FailedToSatisfyReadPreference: Could not find host matching read preference { mode: \"nearest\" } for set atlas-ty53k9-shard-0"}}


*** It looks like this is a MongoDB Atlas cluster. Please ensure that your IP whitelist allows connections from your network.

Error: connect failed to replica set atlas-ty53k9-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00.kupeh.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.kupeh.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.kupeh.mongodb.net:27017 :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

I am using:
windows 10
compass version 1.20.5
MongoDB version 4.4.1

Comment: You're trying to connect to Atlas. Did you Whitelist your IP? Try `0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: also, check your servers are up and running, atlas has a beautiful UI indicating the state of each node.

Comment: Have you included the database name in the URI?